# For positive integers prove that $a\Big|bc \implies a\Big|b \lor a\Big|c$

Tags: divisibility

$a\Big | b,\; b = ak.$  $a\Big|c, c = al,$

So do I multiply $b$ and $c$ to get $a(kl)$ to prove that $bc = a$ multiplied by some integer $kl$ closed under multiplication?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. This is not true. $6$ divides $3 \times 4$ but divides neither factor. Make sure you have correctly stated what you have been asked to prove. [edit] the question to clarify, don't use comments. And use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference (as some editors have done).

Comment: Need to assume $a$ is prime to show this, then it's a fairly well known property of primes.

Answer (score 3):

$6 \mid 2\cdot 3,
6 \not \mid 2,
6 \not \mid 3
$.